# Delay between responses

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using dialogflow to build an open-ended response. This is the code:

```
app.intent('First', (conv) =>{
    conv.ask(qstion[3]);
    conv.add('Option 1 : ' + option[3][0] + 'Option 2: ' + option[3][1]);
});
```

Here, qstion[3] contains the question to be asked. option[3][0] is 'yes' and option[3][1] is 'no'. The speed in which the assistant speaks the option 1 and option 2 is very quick. Is there any way where I can put a delay between the two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to change the response from Google Assistant, have a look at SSML. It is a powerful feature that allows you to tweak response in many different ways.

To add a delay in the speech of Google Assistant, you will need the [break](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/ssml#break) property from SSML.

Comment: Just a simple problem that when I am using the <break> keyword, why does it make a slight beep sound and then provides the next response?

Comment: Beep sound? I've never heard it do that before. Could you show what you are trying to do  in a new question?